# Edit finger so that it does not show no plan

Tags: command-line, shell-script

I have a command `finger {user}` that returns the following:

```sh
Login: {user}                       Name: {user name}
Directory: /home/{user}                 Shell: /bin/bash
On since Thu Aug 12 11:04 (AEST) on tty2 from tty2
   11 days idle
No mail.
No Plan.
```

How to edit this so it does not show no plan?

Comment: Word in the office is that it says no plan so you can sack the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a file called .plan in your home folder.

touch ~/.plan

Comment: New Answer: Plan: Yes